# Why can't I link an resource to a Bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm trying to get a player sprite to be drawn on my form, but when i try it comes up with StackOverflowException. I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?

Player.cs:

```
        private Bitmap p_SpriteIdle1 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.PlayerIdle1);
        private Bitmap p_SpriteIdle2 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.PlayerIdle2);
        private Bitmap p_SpriteWalking1 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.PlayerWalking1);
        private Bitmap p_SpriteWalking2 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.PlayerWalking2);

        public void SpawnInRoom()
        {
            SetSprite(p_SpriteIdle1, p_X, p_Y);
        }

        private void SetSprite(Bitmap sprite, int X, int Y)
        {
            Game game = new Game();
            game.paint_Sprite = sprite;
            game.paint_X = X;
            game.paint_Y = Y;
            game.Invalidate();
        }
```

Game.cs:

```
        private void RePaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (paint_Sprite != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(paint_Sprite, new PointF(paint_X, paint_Y));
            }
        }
```

Comment: To get a StackOverflowException your code must be calling itself either directly or indirectly. If `Invalidate()` causes the sprite to be redrawn and results in another call to `Invalidate()`, you'd end up with a recursion that would only stop with a StackOverflowException

Comment: Oh, sorry. the exception gets thrown at `private Bitmap p_SpriteIdle1 = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.PlayerIdle1);` System.StackOverflowException

Comment: Game game = new Game(); is not likely to be correct.  Bombs when the Game class creates a Player, the Player creates a Game, the Game creates a Player, the Player creates a Game, the Game creates a Player, the Player creates a Game, the... , klaboom.

Comment: You fix it by adding a constructor to Player which takes a Game object, store it in a field of the Player class.  Now the Game can create a player, passing *this*, and the object hierarchy is natural with a player associated with the game they are playing.